# Pass parameter to f:ajax inside c:foreach loop

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to pass a parameter to an ajax event, this is an example of what I mean:

```html
<h:panelGrid id="pictures" columns="3">
    <c:forEach items="#{createProduct.pictures}" var="picture">
        <h:graphicImage value="#{picture.source}" />
        <h:inputText value="#{picture.alt}" />
        <p:commandButton value="Remove">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" 
                    listener="#{createProduct.removePicture(picture)}" 
                    render="@form" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </c:forEach>
</h:panelGrid>
```

I know this code won't work because you cannot pass a parameter through the ajax listener. Though this is merely an example of what I am trying to accomplish. I have tried using `<f:param id="picture" value="#{picture}" />` allong with the ajax tag, though this results in a duplicate component ID form:picture since it is in a loop.
I need this parameter inside the method in order to determine which picture to remove. 
How can I solve this with ajax?

I am using a @ViewScoped CDI-bean.

Answer (score 4):

First, I suggest replacing `c:forEach` with `ui:repeat` tag. Second, as you are using Primefaces, you should use all its strength. So, `commandButton` can be more easily written:

```
<p:commandButton value="Remove" process="@form" update="@form" action="#{createProduct.removePicture(picture)}"/>
```

and that's it. Don't complicate.

By the way, primefaces `commandButton` is sends AJAX request by default, you don't need (and you must not use) `f:ajax` tag.

Comment: @Partlov. I am using `c:forEach` since `ui:repeat` won't work with `h:panelGrid` since `ui:repeat` is a render time tag. I will try the solution with `p:commandButton`.
@KarlKildén. It will work with `f:ajax`, although not with a parameter.

Comment: For some reason the solution with Primefaces` ajax will only fire successfully once, after which it doesn't do anything anymore. My related question in which this is explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796984/primefaces-selectcheckboxmenu-executes-ajax-just-once

Comment: I'm very shore that `p:commandButton` doesn't work with `f:ajax`.

Comment: Ok, and I agree with you that your provided solution SHOULD be the most clean way to perform this. I have tried it myself before, however, it will only allow me to execute a single ajax request.

Comment: Put breakpoint in backing bean's `@PostConstruct` method or constructor. I doubt bean is created in every request (and AJAX request also)